# MacOS IOkit get services by property name in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, iokit

I would like to get all services that contain specific properties.

```
 AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService  <class AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService, id 0x100000a79, registered, matched, active, busy 0 (0 ms), retain 7>
| | | |   |   |     {
| | | |   |   |       "IOMatchedAtBoot" = Yes
| | | |   |   |       "LowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 2
| | | |   |   |       "PrimaryUsagePage" = 65280
| | | |   |   |       "BatteryFaultNotificationType" = "TPBatteryFault"
| | | |   |   |       "HasBattery" = Yes
| | | |   |   |       "VendorID" = 76
| | | |   |   |       "VersionNumber" = 0
| | | |   |   |       "Built-In" = No
| | | |   |   |       "DeviceAddress" = "10-94-bb-ab-b9-53"
| | | |   |   |       "WakeReason" = "Host (0x01)"
| | | |   |   |       "Product" = "Magic Trackpad"
| | | |   |   |       "SerialNumber" = "10-94-bb-ab-b9-53"
| | | |   |   |       "Transport" = "Bluetooth"
| | | |   |   |       "BatteryLowNotificationType" = "TPLowBattery"
| | | |   |   |       "ProductID" = 613
| | | |   |   |       "DeviceUsagePairs" = ({"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=11},{"DeviceUsagePage"=65280,"DeviceUsage"=20})
| | | |   |   |       "IOPersonalityPublisher" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
| | | |   |   |       "MTFW Version" = 920
| | | |   |   |       "BD_ADDR" = <1094bbabb953>
| | | |   |   |       "BatteryPercent" = 42
| | | |   |   |       "BatteryStatusNotificationType" = "BatteryStatusChanged"
| | | |   |   |       "CriticallyLowBatteryNotificationPercentage" = 1
| | | |   |   |       "ReportInterval" = 11250
| | | |   |   |       "RadioFW Version" = 368
| | | |   |   |       "VendorIDSource" = 1
| | | |   |   |       "STFW Version" = 2144
| | | |   |   |       "CFBundleIdentifier" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
| | | |   |   |       "IOProviderClass" = "IOHIDInterface"
| | | |   |   |       "LocationID" = 1001109843
| | | |   |   |       "BluetoothDevice" = Yes
| | | |   |   |       "IOClass" = "AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService"
| | | |   |   |       "HIDServiceSupport" = No
| | | |   |   |       "CFBundleIdentifierKernel" = "com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver"
| | | |   |   |       "ProductIDArray" = (613)
| | | |   |   |       "BatteryStatusFlags" = 0
| | | |   |   |       "ColorID" = 5
| | | |   |   |       "IOMatchCategory" = "IODefaultMatchCategory"
| | | |   |   |       "CountryCode" = 0
| | | |   |   |       "IOProbeScore" = 7175
| | | |   |   |       "PrimaryUsage" = 11
| | | |   |   |       "IOGeneralInterest" = "IOCommand is not serializable"
| | | |   |   |       "BTFW Version" = 368
| | | |   |   |     }
```

Eg. every service that contains the child property `"BatteryPercent"`.

I know that I can get specific service by using `IOServiceNameMatching` and then `IOServiceGetMatchingServices`, but this seems to not be working on the properties inside the service. Is it possible to that? I want to match by BatteryPercent and then also get ProductName.

EDIT: This is the code I'm currently using to get the trackpad battery.

```
func getTrackpadBattery() -> (String, Int) {

    var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
    var object : io_object_t
    var percent: Int = 0
    var productName: String = ""
    let masterPort: mach_port_t = kIOMainPortDefault
    let matchingDict : CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDict, &serialPortIterator)

    if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult {
        repeat {
            object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
            if object != 0 {
                let percentProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "BatteryPercent" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
                if (percentProperty != nil) {
                    percent = (percentProperty?.takeRetainedValue() as? Int)!
                    productName = (IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "Product" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeRetainedValue() as? String)!
                }
                
            }
        } while percent == 0
        IOObjectRelease(object)
    }
    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
    return (productName, percent)
}
```

Comment: Note that your `repeat` / `while` loop looks like it's an infinite loop if no non-zero `BatteryPercent` property is found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry, I don't really know Swift, so my example is in Objective-C and I've attempted to provide it in Swift too but it might not be right.)

The `kIOPropertyExistsMatchKey` matching key should be able to do what you're after. Use it in your matching dictionary to constrain the match results to IOKit services which have the property given. For example:

```
    CFDictionaryRef match_dict =
        (__bridge_retained CFDictionaryRef)
        @{ @kIOPropertyExistsMatchKey : @"BatteryPercent" };

    io_service_t service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(
        kIOMasterPortDefault, match_dict);
```

Note that IOKit properties are for the most part not standardised, so unless you know that a specific service (super-)class publishes the property in a way that your code can process, services could export just about any data via properties with arbitrary names, which does not necessarily map to the meaning you were expecting. So you might want to constrain the registry entries you process in this way to a specific allow-list of  IOService classes. (By adding the `"IOProviderClass"`/`kIOProviderClassKey` matching key to your match dictionary, which is also what `IOServiceMatching()` spits out.) At minimum you might want to warn the user when interpreting data from an unknown service class.

In Swift (may be wrong):

For returning *all* I/O registry entries with the `"BatteryPercent"` property, try something like:

```
    […]
    let matchingDict = [ kIOPropertyExistsMatchKey: "BatteryPercent" ] as NSDictionary
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDict, &iterator)
    […]
```

(You'll need to `import Foundation` to be able to use `NSDictionary`.)

For only returning those objects with a specific class (here: `AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService`) **and** the `"BatteryPercent"` property:

```
    […]
    let matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
    CFDictionarySetValue(matchingDict, kIOPropertyExistsMatchKey, "BatteryPercent")
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDict, &iterator)
    […]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately I'm new to swift and even newer to objective-c so I was not able to translate and verify.

Comment: @pitrisss If you edit your question to include your working Swift code for creating the matching dictionary and then retrieving all the matching services, I might be able to modify it sufficiently to use my suggested matching dictionary. (Especially if your code is stand-alone and complete enough that I can just compile and run it locally.)

Comment: I have edited the question with original function that I'm currently using.

Comment: @pitrisss I've added some Swift code which seems to compile and which should work, but as I mentioned, I barely know any Swift at all, so this might not be the best way to do it in that language.

Comment: the code you added works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a typo, replace

```
while percent == 0
```

with

```
while object != 0
```

As you have only one `percent` and one `productName` property I assume that you expect only one match. If so, add a `break` statement after extracting both values. My suggestion is this code

```
func getTrackpadBattery() -> (String, Int) {

    var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
    var object : io_object_t
    var percent = 0
    var productName = ""
    let masterPort: mach_port_t = kIOMainPortDefault
    let matchingDict : CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDict, &serialPortIterator)

    if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult {
        repeat {
            object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
            if object != 0 {
                if let percentProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "BatteryPercent" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) {
                    percent = percentProperty.takeRetainedValue() as! Int
                }
                if let productProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "Product" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) {
                    productName =  productProperty.takeRetainedValue() as! String
                }
                break
            }
        } while object != 0
        IOObjectRelease(object)
    }
    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
    return (productName, percent)
}
```

If you want to retrieve multiple matches remove the `break` statement, create an array of a custom struct and append the matches

```
struct Device {
    let name : String
    let batteryPercent : Int
}

func getTrackpadBattery() -> [Device] {

    var serialPortIterator = io_iterator_t()
    var object : io_object_t
    var devices = [Device]()
    let masterPort: mach_port_t = kIOMainPortDefault
    let matchingDict : CFDictionary = IOServiceMatching("AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService")
    let kernResult = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, matchingDict, &serialPortIterator)

    if KERN_SUCCESS == kernResult {
        repeat {
            object = IOIteratorNext(serialPortIterator)
            if object != 0 {
                var percent = 0
                var productName = ""
                if let percentProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "BatteryPercent" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) {
                    percent = percentProperty.takeRetainedValue() as! Int
                }
                if let productProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(object, "Product" as CFString, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0) {
                    productName =  productProperty.takeRetainedValue() as! String
                }
                devices.append(Device(name: productName, batteryPercent: percent))
            }
        } while object != 0
        IOObjectRelease(object)
    }
    IOObjectRelease(serialPortIterator)
    return devices
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know there is a typo, this was basically a just a "debug" solution. I wan't to iterate over every device that has certain properties, so in my current solution I am returning a tuple. Thank you, but this really doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Please see the edit. It returns all devices of the `AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService` service.

Comment: I see, but I need to return devices that has battery, not necessarily AppleDevice.